# Steps for troubleshooting Ethernet Cable

Tags: ethernet

A 100 ft ethernet cable (terminated with RJ45) [tests](https://youtu.be/sLoNpIxlMng?t=90):

[image]

The first four cycles should light up green (the first is dark).   Is there a good procedure to systematic narrow down location of the misconnected RJ45 connector or a break in the line?

Any lessons learned are appreciated.  Thank you.

UPDATE:

I found [Ethernet breakout boards](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Dual-RJ45-Ethernet-Connector-Breakout-Board-w-LED-Screw-terminals-NS/302042956654) in a project box.  Maybe a 9V can be connected?  Perhaps the odd terminals can be tied to the + side of a 9V battery and the even terminals connected to the negative terminal?

[image]

Comment: If you have a toner and probe, and the right adapter to apply the tone to that pair in particular, you can just head along the cable and see if the tone is present. I'm not sure if the device you have happens to contain that functionality.

Comment: @nanofarad  Good idea.  If I can find my tone generator and probe that could find the break in the line.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The first step is to inspect or replace the RJ45 jacks installed on each end of the cable being tested.

Comment: Very sensible.  I suspect a janky connection in one of the RJ45 terminals

Comment: Yup. That is the most common problem

Comment: Janky tester connection cables is a close candidate

Comment: Some of the more higher end network switches have a TDR(time domain reflectometer)  feature where they can identify shorts etc and the approximate distance. My TP Link T1500 has this feature.

Comment: Update, RJ45 terminals were replaced and the same symptoms persist.

Answer (score 1):

The real professional way is using a TDRM (time domain reflectometer). It locates the impedance mismatch so it flags where the pair is broken. These things are expensive but I once located rodent damage with less than 50cm of error on a floor run.

The real question with ethernet cable is… what will you do after finding the fault?
Most of the time the correct choice would be to replace the whole cable run…

Comment: Please select and cite a reference link for TDRM.  It would helpful if the acronym was broken out into its four words.  I agree, in all likeliness I will replace the cable run because it is easy / inexpensive (this time).